# How to restrict dropdown values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is the [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vbft1sc4/1658/)

In the JSFiddle there is a drop down filed that will add dynamically.The first selected value should not display in the second added dropdown.So I will not have duplicates problem. How can I achieve this functionality in angularjs.

```
 <select ng-model="personalDetail.fname" ng-repeat="x in names">
</select
     $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
```

and I want to restrict adding the new row dynamically when the drop downs values are completed.

Answer (score 2):

Each drop down will have to track the available names based on the selections made previously

Move the `$scope.names` declaration to the top of your controller

```
$scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
```

Then add a `names` property to your `personalDetail` objects, this property will be used to track the available names based on previous selections

```
$scope.personalDetails = [
{
    'names':$scope.names
}];
```

Now you can modify your addNew function to set the correct number of values when adding a drop down

```
$scope.addNew = function(){
    $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
        'fname': "", 
        'lname': "",
        'email': "",
        // Make a copy of the values set for the previous drop down
        'names': $scope.personalDetails[$scope.personalDetails.length - 1].names.slice() 
        });

        // Determine the value of the previous selected name
        var previousSelectedName = $scope.personalDetails[$scope.personalDetails.length - 2].fname;

        // Get the index of the previous selected name     
        var index = $scope.personalDetails[$scope.personalDetails.length - 1].names.indexOf(previousSelectedName);

        // Remove the name from the valid names list
        if(index > -1){
            $scope.personalDetails[$scope.personalDetails.length - 1].names.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also remember to update the ng-repeat to make use of your new names personalDetail.names property

```
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">                       
    <td>
        <select ng-model="personalDetail.fname" ng-options="x for x in personalDetail.names">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcLqzqq9/) demonstarting this

Please note that I did not handle the case where there are no names available to choose from. But this case should be pretty easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below solution. I guess it solves your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.personalDetails = [{
                'fname': 'Muhammed',
            }];

            $scope.names = ["Muhammed", "Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];

            $scope.namesTemp = ["Muhammed", "Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];

            $scope.addNew = function (personalDetail) {

                if (personalDetail != undefined && personalDetail.fname != undefined) {
                    var index = $scope.namesTemp.indexOf(personalDetail.fname);    // <-- Not supported in <IE9
                    if (index !== -1) {
                        $scope.namesTemp.splice(index, 1);
                    }

                    $scope.personalDetails.push({
                        'fname': "",
                        'lname': "",
                        'email': "",
                    });
                }
            };
            
             $scope.remove = function (index,personalDetail) {

                if (personalDetail != undefined && personalDetail.fname != undefined) {
                   
                        $scope.namesTemp.push(personalDetail.fname);
                   
                    if (index !== -1) {
                        $scope.personalDetails.splice(index, 1);
                    }

                }
            }
        }]);
```

```css
.btn-primary{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.container{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ListController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <select ng-model="personalDetail.fname" ng-options="x for x in names" ng-if="!$last" disabled></select>
                                         <select ng-model="personalDetail.fname" ng-options="x for x in namesTemp" ng-if="$last"></select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove($index,personalDetail)" value="Remove">
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New" ng-click="addNew(personalDetail)" ng-if="$last">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```